# Spring: Single threaded consumer

Tags: netty, spring-rabbit, reactor-netty

Some workers (listeners) have to handle messages one by one in single-thread-style. (Yea, this is weak point, I know.) And looks, I dont know how to set it up right. Application hangs on Spring5 and this block me to move from Spring4.

**I want to highlight**: application should have multiple single threaded listeners. One listener for one queue. I mean some number of . Not multiple listeners for one queue.

I use kotlin. But the trouble is in configuration or even in library bug.

```
@RabbitListener(
        queues = [(queueName1)],
        containerFactory = "exclusiveListenerContainerFactory"
    )
fun handle1(...

@RabbitListener(
        queues = [(queueName2)],
        containerFactory = "exclusiveListenerContainerFactory"
    )
fun handle2(...

@Bean
open fun exclusiveListenerContainerFactory(
    connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
    messageConverter: MessageConverter
): SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory {
    val factory = SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1)
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter)
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false)
    return factory
}
```

I used **SINGLE** exclusiveListener**Container**Factory for each kind on listeners.
And **SINGLE** rabbit**Connection**Factory (instance of CachingConnectionFactory)
I dont know is this right.

### Trouble is:

Some times application hangs on Spring5. On Spring 4 same configuration work well. Funny, that it hands on machine with KVM virtualization. With Virtualbox work well even with Spring5.

jstack https://pastebin.com/MXdHcVAK
top -H -p shows PID 42 consumes all cpu

Some time ago I tried to move to Spring5 with same trouble. I thought it was reactor-netty lib issue, but no luck, they can't reproduce https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/381

I think these two things - configuration and hanging - is bound. But I can't get deeper.

### Update

About dump:
If I understand everything right (I am not sure), cpu consumed by `"tcp-client-loop-nio-4" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fc0de44d800 nid=0x2a runnable` entry in jstack. But I don't know what to do with that.

### Update2

Lead developer of Spring Integration and Spring AMQP - @GaryRussell - approve this configuration. So this issue is about netty I think.

### Update3

This issue was fixed by netty version upgrade.

Comment: Take a thread dump when it hangs to see what the container threads are doing. If you can't figure it out add the dump to the question.

Comment: @GaryRussell it's already here jstack https://pastebin.com/MXdHcVAK
Is my configuration correct?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to RabbitMQ? The container threads are all either blocked waiting for a new message or blocked in reactor code via Stomp. Looks unrelated to RabbitMQ to me.

Comment: I definitely don't know source of lock. I assumed this could be rabbitmq. I thought netty used for rabbit.

Comment: @GaryRussell can you tell something about entry: `"tcp-client-loop-nio-4" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fc0de44d800 nid=0x2a runnable` ?  
https://pastebin.com/BnH4C2F6

Comment: Sorry, no; I have very little experience with netty.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is described configuration correct for "one-thread-consumer"?

Comment: Yes it's fine; but `concurrentConsumers` defaults to 1 anyway.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thank you very much, configuration point was very important for me. Really thank you.